# Django admin.TabularInline auto insert three blank row

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using Tabularline for one of the admin page.

When loaded, it will automatically loaded with 3 empty rows.

How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can set [extra](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.extra) for the inline, which controls how many empty rows are shown.