# Where could those three rows come from?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have three very simple models:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
        date_creation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Personne(BaseModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class Message(BaseModel):
    src = models.ForeignKey('Personne', related_name='message_src')
    dst = models.ForeignKey('Personne', related_name='message_dst')
    message = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True,
                               verbose_name=_(u'Messages'))

    def message_summary(self):
        a = self.message
        if a:
            return (a[:85] + '...') if len(a) > 90 else a
        return u''

    def __str__(self):
        return _(u'{} : {} <> {} : "{}"').format(
            self.date_creation.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
            self.src.full_name(), self.dst.full_name(), self.message_summary()
        )


class Conversation(BaseModel):
    personnes = models.ManyToManyField(Personne)
    messages = models.ManyToManyField(Message)

    def __str__(self):
        return _(u'Conversation n.{}').format(self.pk)
```

Now, in the admin section I declare it like this:

```
class MessageThrough(Conversation.messages.through):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.message)


class ConversationMessagesInline(CollapsedStackedInline):
    model = MessageThrough
    fields = ('message',)
    raw_id_fields = ('message',)

    verbose_name = u"Message"
    verbose_name_plural = u"Messages"


class ConversationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': (('personnes',),)
        }),
        (_(u'Administration only'), {
            'classes': ('collapse',),
            'fields': ('date_v_debut', 'date_v_fin')
        }),
        (_(u'Administration only'), {
            'classes': ('collapse',),
            'fields': ()
        }),
    )
    inlines = (ConversationMessagesInline,)

admin.site.register(Conversation, ConversationAdmin)
admin.site.register(Message)
```

And in the admin section everything works fine:

[image: admin django 1.8]

### But when I try to add, or edit an existing "`Conversation`" I have those three rows "`Messages`" that can't be edited or removed. Where could those rows come from?:

[image: three rows coming from hell / admin django 1.8]

### When I edit a `Conversation` model, same strange thing:

[image: edit django admin problem]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732030/django-admin-tabularinline-auto-insert-three-blank-row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline model admins include extra rows by default to make it easy to add new items. If you don't want them, set [`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.extra]) to 0.

Comment: Thank you but IMHO this is nonsense in a lot of contexts (I cant find a context where it could be useful to "propose 3 more rows you cant remove and you cant edit" actually).

Comment: The extra rows usually are editable. In early versions of Django, there wasn't an 'add another' button, so the extra rows were the only way to add new inlines. I'm not sure why the inlines are not editable in your case. It could be because of your proxy model. I haven't seen the `through` model subclassed like that before.